# Is the direct object implied in this translation? Or does it seem unnatural?

Tags: translation

I'm working with a translation program, trying to translate the following sentence correctly:

The attacker may use a cross-site scripting attack to do this.

The program gives me:

攻撃 者 は 、 クロス サイト スクリプティング 攻撃 を 使用 し て 行 う こと が でき る 。

I don't see the direct object 'this' from the source sentence translated. If this translated sentence followed a sentence mentioning the nature of 'this' (as would normally be the case), would the sentence seem natural (i.e. implied direct object referring to previous sentence)? Or does it seem like something is missing?

I hope I made myself clear, it's kind of hard to explain what I mean...

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on the content of the preceding sentence(s).  If it explained exactly what it is that the attacker is doing/wants to do, that Japanese sentence would be "passable".

However, even if it were explained in the preceding sentence(s), it would still be a good idea to insert a 「それを」 in front of the 「行う」.  In fact, the better writers would do so regardless.

Comment: The sentence is taken from an instruction manual, and I don't know what the preceding sentence was. From the English sentence, I assume 'this' was referred to in the previous sentence. 

After adding some different markers (difficult to explain) to the source sentence, the program gives a different translation これを行う. I would like to know whether the first translation is also acceptable, so that I can determine if both sets of markers give an accurate translation.